# Persisting user data in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, persistence

I have been given a requirement to persist user data once the user has authenticated initially. We don't want to hit the database to look up the user every time they navigate to a new view etc...

I have a User class that is [Serializable] so it could be stored in a session. I am using SQL server for session state as well. I was thinking of storing the object in session but I really hate doing that.

How are developers handling this type of requirement these days?

Comment: What data do you want to persist? Do you mean tracking user activities? Are you using the default win form authentication?

Comment: I have a small user class, with some props in it. userId,username,lastlogin date etc..

Comment: no, I am not using the default formsauthentication or membership provider. Not that that really matters too much in this context though

Comment: I would recommend persist the object in session and cache, session object are not that reliable. And on getting the object you get it from session first, if session is null, get user object from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Encrypting data in cookies and sending it to client, decrypting it whenever you need it
2. Storing it server side by an Id (e.g UserId) in Cache, Session, or any other storage(which is safer than cookie).
3. Use second level caching strategy if you used an ORM

Comment: I am using EF 4 for my ORM I will look into option 3 I suppose.

Comment: WOW, that is a huge load of code for something simple. It also doesn't look like it will play nicely with the way I get my DbContext

Comment: you can use a simple in memory key value based database like memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user object is not huge and does not change often i think it is acceptable to store it in the session.
Since you already have a sql server session you will be making SP calls to pull/push the data already and adding a small object to that should have minimal perf issues compared to other options like persisting it down to the client and sending it back on every request.
 I would also consider the server a much more secure place to keep this info.
You want to minimize the number of times you write to the session(request a lock) when it is stored in sql as it is implemented in a sealed class that exclusivity locks the session.  If any of your other requests in this session require write access to the SQL session they will be blocked by the initial request until it releases the session lock.  (there are some new hooks in .NET 4 for allowing you to change the SessionStateBehavior in the pipeline before the session is accessed)

You might consider a session state server (appfabric) if perf of your SQL session store is an issue.